# How to return data tabel in code, for use in calculated in bokeh?

Tags: python, pandas, user-interface, bokeh

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, gridplot
from bokeh.io import output_file, show, curdoc
from bokeh.models.widgets import FileInput, DataTable, DateFormatter, TableColumn
from pybase64 import b64decode
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import io

# output to static HTML file
output_file("./OUTPUT/001_koreksi.html", title='Koreksi Gayaberat')


def upload_fit_data(attr, old, new):
    print("fit data upload succeeded")
    decoded = b64decode(new)
    f = io.BytesIO(decoded)
    new_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='data')
    # print(new_df)
    data = dict(utmx=new_df['UTM X'],
                utmy=new_df['UTM Y'],
                elev=new_df['Elevasi'],
                lat=new_df['Latitude'],
                lon=new_df['Longitude'],
                ta=new_df['Tinggi Alat'],
                N=new_df['N'],
                E=new_df['E'],
                S=new_df['S'],
                W=new_df['W'],
                time=new_df['Time'],
                kt=new_df['Koreksi Tide'],
                rdgrav=new_df['Bacaan'])
    source = ColumnDataSource(data)

    columns = [TableColumn(field="utmx", title="UTM X"), TableColumn(field="utmy", title="UTM Y"),
               TableColumn(field="elev", title="Elevasi"), TableColumn(field="lat", title="Latitude"),
               TableColumn(field="lon", title="Longitude"), TableColumn(field="ta", title="Tinggi Alat"),
               TableColumn(field="N", title="North"), TableColumn(field="E", title="East"),
               TableColumn(field="S", title="South"), TableColumn(field="W", title="West"),
               TableColumn(field="time", title="Waktu Pengukuran"), TableColumn(field="kt", title="Koreksi tide"),
               TableColumn(field="rdgrav", title="Bacaan Alat")]
    data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=500, height=300)
    global data_table

    # return data_table


# data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=500, height=300)
file_input = FileInput(accept=".xlsx")
file_input.on_change('value', upload_fit_data)


p = gridplot([file_input, data_table])
doc = curdoc()
doc.add_root(p)
```

Question: how to use and show "data_table" value in bokeh application? if i run this code, in bokeh interface the "data_table" not show

Comment: Your code is not runnable. 1) what is `pybase64`, did you mean `base64`? 2) `upload_fit_data` does not return anything. 3) you are assigning a value to `data_table` and then immediately trying to declare is as global. This is not valid.  4) you try and create a gridplot using the value `data_table` which is not visible outside the scope of `upload_fit_data`. I think you meant to return `data_table` and then use the result in the plot... but I don't know that for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from the issues mentioned in the comment to your question by Z4-tier, there are others:

- `output_file` will not work with `bokeh serve` - and `bokeh serve` is exactly what you need given that you want to run Python code in response to users' actions in the web UI
- `gridplot` accepts a list of tuples that specify not only the items themselves but also where to put each item. Since you have only two widgets, `column` should be sufficient

Consider this working code:

```
import io
from base64 import b64decode

import pandas as pd

from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.models.widgets import FileInput, DataTable, TableColumn

column_map = dict(utmx='UTM X', utmy='UTM Y', elev='Elevasi',
                  lat='Latitude', lon='Longitude', ta='Tinggi Alat',
                  N='N', E='E', S='S', W='W', time='Time',
                  kt='Koreksi Tide', rdgrav='Bacaan')

source = ColumnDataSource(data={c: [] for c in column_map})

columns = [TableColumn(field="utmx", title="UTM X"), TableColumn(field="utmy", title="UTM Y"),
           TableColumn(field="elev", title="Elevasi"), TableColumn(field="lat", title="Latitude"),
           TableColumn(field="lon", title="Longitude"), TableColumn(field="ta", title="Tinggi Alat"),
           TableColumn(field="N", title="North"), TableColumn(field="E", title="East"),
           TableColumn(field="S", title="South"), TableColumn(field="W", title="West"),
           TableColumn(field="time", title="Waktu Pengukuran"), TableColumn(field="kt", title="Koreksi tide"),
           TableColumn(field="rdgrav", title="Bacaan Alat")]
data_table = DataTable(source=source, columns=columns, width=500, height=300)


def upload_fit_data(attr, old, new):
    f = io.BytesIO(b64decode(new))
    new_df = pd.read_excel(f, sheet_name='data')
    source.data = {ds_c: new_df[df_c] for ds_c, df_c in column_map.items()}


file_input = FileInput(accept=".xlsx")
file_input.on_change('value', upload_fit_data)

curdoc().add_root(column(file_input, data_table))
```

Note that if you don't want to have an interactive web page and just want to have a static HTML file, then you cannot use any Python callbacks. You will have to specify the XLSX file via the CLI and process the data right when the script runs.